# Function that allows Alexa to go into detail about a slot?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Currently I have my Alexa skill able to answer my question as well as repeat the answer she gave to me. Is there a function that allows Alexa to go into detail about a list she wrote off?

I have tried making multiple intents. It seems that it would work, but would be verrry repetitive and time consuming. I felt that there would be a more efficient way but I could not seem to find what I was looking for on the amazon.developers web page.

I expect that if I respond with something from the list that Alexa referenced that my response (if included in the list) would be able to get a response back from Alexa with more in-depth information on my response.

Example:

Me: "Alexa, open pencil box"

Alexa: "Your pencil box is now open. There are green, red, purple, yellow, blue, and orange pencils. Would you like me to repeat this list? If so, say repeat. If not, pick a pencil color you would like to know more about.

Me: "Blue"

Alexa: "The blue colored pencil is great for skies, oceans, and layers for 'cool' colors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you mean by "Is there a function that allows Alexa to go into detail about a list she wrote off?"
Also, please describe what you have tried so far and provide the JSON code for your interactionModel (your utterances, slots etc.)

According to my interpretation, you need two things:

1. Your default or "launch" intent which gets triggered by "Alexa, open pencil box" and responds with Alexa: "Your pencil box is now open.[...]"
2. 'A second intent, e.g. "ColorDetailIntent" which gets triggered when you say a color. It should have one slot, e.g. {color_name} of type "AMAZON.Color" (see [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html)). When this gets triggered, you can get the slot's value. According to the value you can then send the appropriate response. If the value is blue Alexa: "The blue colored pencil[...]" and so on.

If I understood correctly, you already have implemented 1. So 2. should point you in the right direction. If you have problems grasping this, you will need to get a basic understanding for Alexa Skill Kit first. You can find my approach to learning about ASK for Python [here](https://data-dive.com/building-custom-skill-for-alexa). It includes links to several tutorials and documentations which you can go through one by one. 
For node.js you might want to take a look at one of the many samples provided [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs).

Comment: Wow this was the sort of answer I was looking for. Do you think I would be able to message you for more detailed descriptions? The end of the second point you made regarding  responding with an appropriate response based on he value of the slot is the type of information I've been missing.